# Render Three.js into a div element

Tags: html, render, three.js

I am using Three.js. Having a html site with two div elements, is it possible to render just in one div element?

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <div id="twocols">
        <div id="detailinfo">
            <span class="c">Detailinformationen:</span><br/>
            <span id="tb" class="g"></span><br/>
            <span class="c">Grafiken:</span>
            <div id="chart"></div>
            <div id="chart2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="city">
        </div>                  
    </div>      
</body>
```

I want to render into the city div.

Three.js Code:

```
function initScene() {

            //container = document.createElement('div');
            //document.body.appendChild(container);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            createCamera();
            createLight();
            createProjector();
            createRenderer();
            createControls();

            //...
        }
```

createRenderer:

```
function createRenderer() {
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias : ANTIALIAS, 
                preserveDrawingBuffer : DRAWINGBUFFER
            });

            renderer.setSize(document.getElementById("city").offsetWidth, document.getElementById("city").offsetHeight);
            document.getElementById("city").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            THREEx.Screenshot.bindKey(renderer); // add the printscreen shortcut with "p"
        }
```

createControls:

```
function createControls() {
            controls = new InteractionManager(camera, document.getElementById("city"));
            //...
        }
```

InteractionManager.js

```
initialize: function(camera, domElement) {

    this.object = camera;
    this.domElement = (domElement !== undefined) ? domElement : document;
    this.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
    //this.chartManager = new ChartsManager();

    if ( this.domElement === document ) {
        this.viewHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        this.viewHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    } else {
        this.viewHalfX = this.domElement.offsetWidth / 2;
        this.viewHalfY = this.domElement.offsetHeight / 2;
        //alert(domElement.offsetWidth + "  " + domElement.offsetHeight);
        //this.domElement.setAttribute( 'tabindex', -1 );
    }

    //...
},
```

so far..

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
container = document.createElement('div');
```

Use:

```
container = document.getElementById('city');
```

Comment: thank you, at the moment I dont use container anymore, but doesnt work so for.

Comment: Hard to say. Use debugger (F12). Check what you get from `document.getElementById("city")`. And about your original question, about rendering in a div, look this example: http://jsfiddle.net/eLudu/

Comment: The fiddle above doesn't work for me, Juan. Just displays a bordered box with nothing in it.